# Programming Simple Tag Handlers in JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, tags, tag-handler

I recently started working on JSP, and I was going through the tutorials on creating simple tag handlers for validating custom tags. I came across this code snippet and when I tried to run it, I am getting the same error over and over again. I asks me to change the return type first, and then it tell that the new return type is incompatible with the method being overridden.
Thing is, I just copied the code from docs.oracle.com

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnann.html

Can anyone tell what's wrong here ?

***EDIT : I have now added the imports and the error message.***

```
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagData;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.TagExtraInfo;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.ValidationMessage;

public class TwaTEI extends TagExtraInfo {
    public ValidationMessage[] validate(TagData data) {
        Object o = data.getAttribute("attr1");
        if (o != null && o != TagData.REQUEST_TIME_VALUE) {
            if (((String)o).toLowerCase().equals("true") ||
                 ((String)o).toLowerCase().equals("false") )
                 return null;
            else
                return new ValidationMessage(data.getId(),
                    "Invalid boolean value.");
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

***ERROR***

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ValidationMessage to ValidationMessage[].
```

Comment: The imports are the key part here, but you didn't post them. And you didn't post the exact and complete error message you got from the compiler either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part is invalid, you should return an array of ValidationMessage objects:

```
return new ValidationMessage(data.getId(),
                "Invalid boolean value.");
```

Like this:

```
return new ValidationMessage[]{new ValidationMessage(data.getId(),
                "Invalid boolean value.")};
```